# File i/o and buffer manipulation in c

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C. I am making a simple game in c.
I have a .txt file that stores players' score such as

```
gse
12
CKY 
8
asf
8
FWD
7
BCS
6
BBC
5
PYS
4
NSE
3
Jaeh
2
PJH
1
```

and the one of the functions in my c code is the following:

```
void ViewScoreBoard() { 
int n = 0;
int c;
char buffer[NAME_LENGTH] = { 0 };
FILE *fp = fopen("scoreBoard.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("no score\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return;
}

system("cls");//clears the screen

printf("=======SCORE=======\n");
if (fp){
   while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp)!=NULL){
        if(n%2==0){
            printf("%2d. ",n/2+1); //index
            buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0; //stripes the newline chr
            printf("%5s",buffer);            
        }
        if(n%2==1){
            printf("%5s",buffer);
        }
        n++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

printf("Enter AnyKeys");
Sleep(100);
getchar();
getchar();}
```

The problem is this.
On the console, the score is printed out fine up until 3.(before Jaeh)

```
=======SCORE=======
 1.   gse  12
 2.   CKY   8
 3.   asf   8
 4.   FWD   7
 5.   BCS   6
 6.   BBC   5
 7.   PYS   4
 8.   NSE   3
 9.  Jaeh
10.     2 PJH
11.     1Enter AnyKeys
```

I need 2 to be inline with Jaeh but don't know what's wrong...
Thanks in advance!

***EDIT

changed the code to `char buffer[NAME_LENGTH+2] = { 0 };` and everything works fine.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Note: follow-up to OP's [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239406/first-character-in-txt-file-doesnt-print-in-c)

Comment: seems that the input has some empty lines.

Comment: Calling `fflush` with an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as *undefined behavior*. Some implementations allow it as an *extension* of the language, but please try to avoid it.

Comment: Show what `NAME_LENGTH` is.

Comment: UV for `//stripes the newline chr` but that should be just after `fgets`.

Comment: @WeatherVane 
   `#define NAME_LENGTH 5
    #define LIST_LENGTH 10`

Comment: @WeatherVane I think OP wants the newline in there when printing the score. Note the lack of a newline char in the `printf`.

Comment: @Py11 "Jaeh" + '\n' + '\0' requires 6 chars.

Comment: My comment from a deleted answer: the buffer size is too small, which is where things go wrong. The fault is because there was not enough room for the newline, which gets read on the next iteration. So don't be mean with the `fgets` buffer size, it's a one-off and its content will be processed and passed on to smaller things.

Comment: I did not see the comment with the buffer size being too small and I assumed it was big enough when I tested it - that led to my wrong answer. Decided it's best to delete the wrong answer:).

Comment: It was the comment from @JohnnyMopp above. 4 + 1 + 1 = 6.

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed, but I missed the comment with `#define NAME_LENGTH 5`, so when I tested it I tested with big enough buffer, assuming it was big enough in the original code. Sometimes correct code leads to incorrect answers:).

Comment: changed the code to `char buffer[NAME_LENGTH+2] = { 0 };` and everything works fine.

Comment: @Py11 don't be mean define `char buffer[100]`